# iOS: Control access to camera roll new appear

Tags: ios, image, camera-roll, alauthorizationstatus

in my app I use `ALAssetsLibrary` to load access at photos in camera roll; 
The first time I start my app I see the classic message, if I want give the permission to access at the photo library or not.

But I want to test this situation in each case (allow and not allowed) but I'm not able show again this message; I tried to delete app, change number version, change bundle identifier, but nothing!

Every time I run my app it not show me this message and I have ever the permission to access in the library image; I want to test what happen if I select NO.

(I know that I can change this option in general settings, but in this case I control all in `viewdidappear`)
I want to know what happen If I select no with that message, then is it possible show again that alert?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got your question. In your simulator just goto Settings-->Privacy-->Photos-->You app.

[image]

Just off that switch each time and you will get prompted with that message..!

Answer (score 0):

Once a user has allowed or disallowed you app access the message will never be shown again and iOS save this permission not to bother the user again.

For the iOS simulator you can rest the settings to get the message again.

Comment: Is there any documentation link . I need it